# I am trying to call a method from the another class without importing or hardcoding it. Turning a string into code/script

Tags: string, groovy

I am trying to call a method from the Example1Test class without importing or hardcoding it. I've read that String.execute() is the way to go; however, I cannot get it to work. Please can someone advise me on where I am going wrong/how to fix it?

I appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you in advance :)

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = "dummyTests.Example1Test.runTest()".execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
```

Comment: string.execute starts a new system process/executeble. it's not about function call. http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute() Probably you are looking for `Eval.me("dummyTests.Example1Test.runTest()")`

Comment: Class testClass = “dummyTests.ExampleTest”; testClass.runTest()